# How can I get the child divs to match the height of the parent?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 about-info js-matchheight" data-wow-offset="10">
        <div class="border">
          <h3>About Me</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 about-container js-matchheight noPadding" data-wow-offset="10">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block">
              <h4>Weddings</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block">
              <h4>Studio</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block">
              <h4>Nature</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block">
              <h4>Events</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need help achieving a layout like this:

Desired layout

[image]

I'm having trouble getting the child divs on the right to match the height of the parent.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I assumed that's bootstrap 3.x with the `-xs-` prefixes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have a row with columns on the right hand side but I'm struggling to fill that blue space. I can somewhat get what I want adding padding to the "block" class but it's never going to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for your solution. Please check

```css
.h-100{
  height:100%;
}
.h-50{
  height:50%;
}
.block{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 about-info js-matchheight" data-wow-offset="10">
            <div class="border">
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 about-container js-matchheight noPadding" data-wow-offset="10">
            <div class="container-fluid h-100">
                <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block h-50">
                      <div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100 justify-content-center"><h4>Weddings</h4> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block h-50">
                      <div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100 justify-content-center"><h4>Studio</h4> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block h-50">
                      <div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100 justify-content-center"><h4>Nature</h4> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block h-50">
                      <div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100 justify-content-center"> <h4>Events</h4> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: I added bootstrap 4.5.2 CSS. and In this CSS used the latest flex techniques. as per this parent row's column have equal height. and then after creating height CSS(h-100 and h-50). h-100 class add to child row and h-50 class add to child column. Means created 50 50 50 50 layout. but inner child content shows at the top side. so add flex class to that inner div and also add these classes(align-items-center h-100 justify-content-center).
align-items-center -> vertical center based on height
justify-content-center  -> horizontal center based on width

Answer (score 1):

In order for children to match the width and height of their parent element you need to remove all padding and margins from the child element. You can then set the height and the width of the child to 100%. The height and width would then be controlled by the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-fluid .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-info {
  margin: 40px;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-info .border {
  border: 1px solid #0086c5;
  padding: 40px;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-info .border h3 {
  color: #0086c5;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-container .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  background: #0086c5;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-container .container-fluid .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-container .container-fluid .row > div {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-container .container-fluid .row > div h4 {
  align-self: center;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-container .container-fluid .row > div:not(:nth-child(2n)) {
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}
.container-fluid .row .about-container .container-fluid .row > div:not(:nth-last-child(-n + 2)) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 about-info js-matchheight" data-wow-offset="10">
        <div class="border">
          <h3>About Me</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 about-container js-matchheight noPadding" data-wow-offset="10">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block">
              <h4>Weddings</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block">
              <h4>Studio</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block">
              <h4>Nature</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 block">
              <h4>Events</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: I used css gird and flexbox,